# Creating virtual env

Tags: python, virtualenv, new-project

Hi I am going to start a pretty big project in python. I need to use virtual environment for my packages.

Where should I create it?

If my project is in D:\my_project directory should I create env in the same directory?
Or should it be on the same drive instance?
Or it completely doesn't matter where I create that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvirtualenv%5D+where+create

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really matter, the virtual environment is just somewhere to keep everything together and have all the parts of the program in one place for referencing purposes. You can move it about between drives and systems and it should still work. Whether you want to then put that virtual environment directory inside a parent folder that holds other stuff like unused assets, notes, your own personal work materials pertaining to the project is up to you, that's what I tend to do!